# Embed videos using the YoxView module

Tags: 7

How is it possible to embed videos using the [YoxView](http://drupal.org/project/yoxview) module in Drupal 7?
Alas, this module doesn't seem to have documentation on how to use it.

It seems ALL possible on the [YoxView Official Website](http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/).
I've managed to use its image viewer easily and perfectly, but I got no clue on using the video embedder.